# How to get results reported to email from macro action PPT

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PPT quiz that functions of macro actions. It counts the `numberCorrect` and the `numberWrong` and reports these scores to the user at the end of the quiz when they press the "see my results" box.

I would like these scores to be automatically reported to me when they select this box because I do not want the users taking the test numerous times prior to submitting their results.

Everyone will be using a G-mail account.

Here is my current visual basic module if that helps:

```
Dim UserName As String
Dim numberCorrect As Integer
Dim numberWrong As Integer

Sub YourName()
UserName = InputBox(Prompt:="Type Your Name!")
MsgBox " Good Luck " + UserName, vbApplicationModal, " IEE Recognition Training"

End Sub

Sub Correct()
MsgBox " Well Done! That's The Correct Answer " + UserName, vbApplicationModal, " IEE Recognition Training"
numberCorrect = numberCorrect + 1
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub

Sub Wrong()
MsgBox " Sorry! That's The Wrong Answer " + UserName, vbApplicationModal, "  IEE Recognition Training"
numberWrong = numberWrong + 1
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub

Sub Start()
numberCorrect = 0
numberWrong = 0
YourName
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub

Sub Results()
MsgBox ("You Got " & numberCorrect & " Correct Answers, " & numberWrong & " Wrong Answers, " & UserName), vbApplicationModal, "  IEE Recognition Training"
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily with the Outlook object model in VBA but are the users using that client to connect to GMail accounts or are they using a web client? If you don't use an Outlook object in your VBA code, you'd be looking at direct use of SMTP which is a much more complicated beast. Here is an Outlook snippet using late binding:

```
        Set oOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set oEmail = oOL.CreateItem(0) ' olMailItem = 0
        With oEmail
            .BodyFormat = 1 ' olFormatPlain = 1
            .Subject = "Automatic results"
            .Body = "You Got " & numberCorrect & " Correct Answers, " & numberWrong & " Wrong Answers, " & UserName
            .To = "admin@mydomain.com"
            .Send
        End With
        Set oOL = Nothing: Set oEmail = Nothing
```